# linux memory consumption redhat. how to view memory usage

Tags: memory, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have red hat 6.2
The CPU is extremely busy.

```
top - 06:58:03 up 2 days, 18:09,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
Tasks:  93 total,   1 running,  92 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.0%us,  0.2%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.8%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   1695484k total,  1653244k used,    42240k free,   154000k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,   364752k cached
```

How can I see what is taking most memory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CPU appears to be doing almost exactly nothing (99.8% idle). Much, but not all, memory is allocated, no swap is used. There seem to be no problems...

You should read the man page for `top`: 
use the keys '<' and '>' to change the sort order, pressing 'B' then 'x' should highlight
the sorting column. Or 'F' to choose sorting column from a menu instead.

If the `top` display is too limiting, then `ps` can do similar:

```
 ps axwwo "pid user size rss etime cputime args" | sort -n -k +4
```

to sort numerically by the 4th column, rss (resident memory).